# How to approach this counting problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

> Let $n ≥ 1$ be an integer. A function $f : \{1, 2, \ldots , n\} \to \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is considered "valid", if there is at least one integer $i$ in $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ for which $f(i) = i$.
>
> Determine the number of valid functions.

I'm having problems understanding what this question is asking. I'm not even sure how to approach this. Could someone point me to the right direction? What technique should I be using to approach it?

I guess what's confusing me the most is this line here. Since I don't understand it.

A function $f : \{1, 2, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$

Comment: First, do you know what a function technically is defined as?  A function $f~:~\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ means that the function's name is $f$, its domain is $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, its codomain is $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and the fact that it is a function means that it is technically a collection of pairs of elements, with the left element in each pair taken from the domain and the right element in each pair taken from the codomain such that every element in the *domain specifically* appears in *exactly one* pair.

Comment: That a notation indicating that $f:A\to B$ takes an element $a$ from $A$ and maps it to an element $b$ of $B$.

Comment: For example with the domain $\{1,2\}$ and codomain $\{a,b\}$ you have the following functions $f=\{(1,a),(2,a)\},g=\{(1,a),(2,b)\},h=\{(1,b),(2,a)\},j=\{(1,b),(2,b)\}$.  We notate for simplicity $f(x)$ as the element which is paired with the element $x$, in the above example that would be $f(1)=a$ and $f(2)=a$, or $h(1)=b,h(2)=a$, etc...

Comment: As for an approach on how to count... this is a standard exercise in the use of inclusion-exclusion and multiplication principles with nothing special or tricky about it.

Answer (score 18):

For each of the $n$ elements of the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of the function $f$, we must choose one element of the [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)). There are $n$ possibilities to choose from in the range. This means that the total number of functions from $\{1,2,\,...\,,n\}$ to $\{1,2,\,...\,,n\}$ is $$n^n$$

However, we have a restriction that your function has at least one [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)).

Let's count the number of functions with *no fixed points* and subtract this from the total number of functions.

For each element of the domain, one choice from the range is not allowed.

We have $n-1$ choices for each of the $n$ elements of the domain.

This means that the number of functions from $\{1,2,\,...\,,n\}$ to $\{1,2,\,...\,,n\}$ with no fixed points is

$$(n-1)^{n}\,$$

The number of functions from $\{1,2,\,...\,,n\}$ to $\{1,2,\,...\,,n\}$ with *at least one* fixed point is equal to the total number of functions from $\{1,2,\,...\,,n\}$ to $\{1,2,\,...\,,n\}$, minus the number of functions with *no* fixed points.  This is our final answer:

$$n^n - (n-1)^n$$

Comment: Famously, the relative number of "valid" functions is close to $1-\frac{1}{e}$ for large $n$, $$\frac{n^n - (n-1)^n}{n^n} = 1-\left( 1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^n \approx 1-\frac{1}{e} \approx 0.63$$

Answer (score 7):

Let $A_i$ denote the number of functions for which $f(i) = i$. We need $\left|\cup_{i=1}^n A_i\right|$. Note that $|A_i| = n^{n-1}$. Also $|A_i \cap A_j| = n^{n-2}$. Thus by inclusion exclusion principle,
$$\left|\cup_{i=1}^n A_i\right| = \binom{n}{1}n^{n-1} - \binom{n}{2}n^{n-2} +\cdots =n^n - (n-1)^n$$

Comment: I don't think inclusion-exclusion is necessary to solve this problem, I think it makes it unnecessarily complicated. There's a direct way to achieve the final answer.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee inclusion-exclusion however is an acceptable approach and is the most common approach to the similar problem of finding the number of *permutations* with at least one fixed point (*other approaches involving recurrence*).  That makes this solution a direct analog to the solution to the related problem which I think is valuable.

Answer (score 7):

There $n^n$ functions $\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ in total, since for every argument $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ we have $n$ choices.

There are $(n-1)^n$ functions that are **not** valid, since for these functions for every argument $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ we have $n-1$ choices (the choice "$i$" falls out).

Consequently there are $n^n-(n-1)^n$ valid functions.